# Plotting a csv file?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a file csv file, in this file how I can plot `D18:D10000` versus `E18:E10000;` I used `[v,t]= scop('H.csv')` with considering following function but did not work:

```
function [v,t]=scope( filename )
    v=xlsread(filename,'','E18:E10000');
    t=xlsread(filename,'','D18:D10000');
    plot(t,v)
```

Comment: I do not get plot, I have just following 
v = [] t =[]

Comment: I would try `v=xlsread(filename,'E18:E10000');`

Comment: Or maybe `csvread` may work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the sheet (second argument) by either name or number:

```
xlsread(filename,'Sheet1','E18:E10000');
```

or

```
xlsread(filename,1,'E18:E10000');
```

Note the apostrophes!

Also xlsread has up to 3 output arguments:

```
[Num, Txt, Raw] = xlsread(...)
```

You may need to use the Raw output if your data contains both text and nums.

Try

```
help xlsread
```